# How to calculate if a day is between two dates?

Tags: r, dataframe, date

I have a data with entry and exit dates per individual. My data looks like this:

```
  ID      entry       exit
1  1 01.01.2010 31/01/2016
2  2 01/02/2016 01/01/2021
3  3 01/10/2010 30/09/2019
4  4 01.09.2013 31/12/2015
5  5 01/01/2016 30/09/2020
```

I would like to create extra columns, in which I would like to identify if the individual was active (so between the dates of entry and exit) to a given date.

The data should look something like this:

```
 ID      entry    exit           active_31_12_2011    active_31_12_2016
1  1 01/01/2010 31/01/2016               yes                no
2  2 01/02/2016 01/01/2021                no               yes
3  3 01/10/2010 30/09/2019               yes               yes
4  4 01/09/2013 31/12/2015                no                no
5  5 01/01/2016 30/09/2020                no               yes
```

Does anyone has an idea how I could do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `data.table::between`

```
df %>%
  mutate(entry = as.Date(entry, format = "%d/%m/%Y"),
         exit = as.Date(exit, format = "%d/%m/%Y")) %>%
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(active_31_12_2011 = between(as.Date("2011/12/31"),lower = entry, upper = exit),
         active_31_12_2016 = between(as.Date("2016/12/31"),lower = entry, upper = exit))

     ID entry      exit       active_31_12_2011 active_31_12_2016
  <int> <date>     <date>     <lgl>             <lgl>            
1     1 2010-01-01 2016-01-31 TRUE              FALSE            
2     2 2016-02-01 2021-01-01 FALSE             TRUE             
3     3 2010-10-01 2019-09-30 TRUE              TRUE             
4     4 2013-09-01 2015-12-31 FALSE             FALSE            
5     5 2016-01-01 2020-09-30 FALSE             TRUE
```

To get yes/no output,

```
df %>%
  mutate(entry = as.Date(entry, format = "%d/%m/%Y"),
         exit = as.Date(exit, format = "%d/%m/%Y")) %>%
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(active_31_12_2011 = ifelse(between(as.Date("2011/12/31"),lower = entry, upper = exit), "Yes", "No"),
         active_31_12_2016 = ifelse(between(as.Date("2016/12/31"),lower = entry, upper = exit), "Yes", "No"))

     ID entry      exit       active_31_12_2011 active_31_12_2016
  <int> <date>     <date>     <chr>             <chr>            
1     1 2010-01-01 2016-01-31 Yes               No               
2     2 2016-02-01 2021-01-01 No                Yes              
3     3 2010-10-01 2019-09-30 Yes               Yes              
4     4 2013-09-01 2015-12-31 No                No               
5     5 2016-01-01 2020-09-30 No                Yes
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked!

Answer (score 1):

When the dates are `dates` or are formatted like 2010-01-01 you can use `==`, `>`, `<`, `>=` or `<=`.

```
x$active_31_12_2011 <- c("no", "yes")[1 + (x$entry <= "2011-12-31" & "2011-12-31" <= x$exit)]
x$active_31_12_2016 <- c("no", "yes")[1 + (x$entry <= "2016-12-31" & "2016-12-31" <= x$exit)]

x
#  ID      entry       exit active_31_12_2011 active_31_12_2016
#1  1 2010-01-01 2016-01-31               yes                no
#2  2 2016-02-01 2021-01-01                no               yes
#3  3 2010-10-01 2019-09-30               yes               yes
#4  4 2013-09-01 2015-12-31                no                no
#5  5 2016-01-01 2020-09-30                no               yes
```

Data:

```
x <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="ID      entry       exit
1  1 01/01/2010 31/01/2016
2  2 01/02/2016 01/01/2021
3  3 01/10/2010 30/09/2019
4  4 01/09/2013 31/12/2015
5  5 01/01/2016 30/09/2020")
x$entry <- as.Date(x$entry, "%d/%m/%Y")
x$exit <- as.Date(x$exit, "%d/%m/%Y")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how to do it using `lubridate`:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date, intersect, setdiff, union

data <- tribble(
  ~ID, ~entry, ~exit,
  1, "01/01/2010", "31/01/2016",
  2, "01/02/2016", "01/01/2021",
  3, "01/10/2010", "30/09/2019",
  4, "01/09/2013", "31/12/2015",
  5, "01/01/2016", "30/09/2020"
)

data %>%
  mutate_at(c("entry", "exit"), ~ .x %>% parse_date(format = "%d/%m/%Y")) %>%
  mutate(
    interval = interval(entry, exit),
    active_31_12_2011 = ymd("2011-12-31") %within% interval,
    active_31_12_2016 = ymd("2016-12-31") %within% interval
  )
#> # A tibble: 5 x 6
#>      ID entry      exit       interval                       active_31_12_2011
#>   <dbl> <date>     <date>     <Interval>                     <lgl>            
#> 1     1 2010-01-01 2016-01-31 2010-01-01 UTC--2016-01-31 UTC TRUE             
#> 2     2 2016-02-01 2021-01-01 2016-02-01 UTC--2021-01-01 UTC FALSE            
#> 3     3 2010-10-01 2019-09-30 2010-10-01 UTC--2019-09-30 UTC TRUE             
#> 4     4 2013-09-01 2015-12-31 2013-09-01 UTC--2015-12-31 UTC FALSE            
#> 5     5 2016-01-01 2020-09-30 2016-01-01 UTC--2020-09-30 UTC FALSE            
#> # … with 1 more variable: active_31_12_2016 <lgl>
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You could voluntarily coerce the dates to integers and use `data.table::between`.

```
dat_n <- as.data.frame(lapply(dat, as.integer))

library(data.table)
act <- t(apply(dat_n[-1], 1, \(z) between(as.numeric(x), z[1], z[2]))) |>
  `colnames<-`(paste0('active_', x))
res <- cbind(dat, act)
res
#   ID      entry       exit active_2011-12-31 active_2016-12-31
# 1  1 2010-01-01 2016-01-31              TRUE             FALSE
# 2  2 2016-02-01 2021-01-01             FALSE              TRUE
# 3  3 2010-10-01 2019-09-30              TRUE              TRUE
# 4  4 2013-09-01 2015-12-31             FALSE             FALSE
# 5  5 2016-01-01 2020-09-30             FALSE              TRUE
```

---

*Data*

```
dat <- structure(list(ID = 1:5, entry = structure(c(14610, 16832, 14883, 
15949, 16801), class = "Date"), exit = structure(c(16831, 18628, 
18169, 16800, 18535), class = "Date")), row.names = c("1", "2", 
"3", "4", "5"), class = "data.frame")

x <- c(as.Date('2011-12-31'), as.Date('2016-12-31'))
```